# Java Web Start Application can read files from local systems, but not write

Tags: java, file, local, jnlp, java-web-start

please ask if you need more info. I have the security and all permissions tags
 
in my jnlp, and when I run my java app offline it works correctly.

```
File T = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ".myapp/");<br />
if(!T.exists())
    T.mkdirs();
File[] temp=new File[2];

temp[0] = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator +
                   ".myapp"+File.separator+"temp1.txt");
temp[1] = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator +
                   ".myapp"+File.separator+"temp2.txt");

writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp[x]));
writer.write(finalData);
writer.close();
```

I use the following method to write to files I want to create in a directory in the user's system. In the program, I also read from the same folder and when I place test data in that folder it works correctly. When I remove the temp1.txt and temp2.txt files it does not read any data. No error messages come up or anything.

To reiterate, when ran in java web start, the window pops up and the program runs correctly with no error messages, but it does not write the files properly to the users system. At the same time, when test data is provided in .txt files, it reads it correctly.

Edit: If it is at all possible, could there be a solution without using some of the javaw.jnlp.* methods? The program really has to have a folder with .txt files to read from

edit2: All my jars are signed as well

Comment: What does your policy file look like?

Comment: what is the policy file? I do not know if I even have one

Comment: JNLP can either use a policy file or a `<security>` block that outlines what the application is allowed to do on the host machine. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html or https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9673721 for some info.

Comment: wait...but since I already have a security block, won't it not look at the policy file?

Comment: Yeah, is your security block `all-permissions`?

Comment: yes it is. <security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>

Comment: That's very odd. In some cases, a 32-bit VM returns odd results for `System.getProperty("user.home")` when running on 64-bit systems but that's the only thing I can think of as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys, I was an idiot. My jnlp file pointed to a different version of my java program in my local system and basically I'm an idiot. When I went home, I tested the website from my home pc and found my error.

Thanks so much for your help though!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try creating the file, before using it?.

`temp[1].createNewFile()`

This will create the file only if it doesn't exist. You can use return boolean flag to find out if the file already exists. This method will also throw an *IOException* if the security manager denies the create request.

EDIT:

According to `java.io.FileWriter`, file creation depends upon the underlying platform. Since you are able to read the file if it exists and only having problem with creating a new file in a JNLP app. I suggested creating a new file using `createNewFile` instead of relying on FileWriter to create the file.

From `java.io.FileWriter` javadoc:

> Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the
>   underlying platform.