# How to get a http path for a file in local dir?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am using Tomcat, Eclipse to develop my web app.
For a file in the directory "E:\Dictionary\data\a.mp3", I need the equivalent http path(eg, "lcalhost:8080/MyApp/data/a.mp3"). So that the mp3 can be played in a flash player. 
How can I get it?

Comment: put it in your project folder

Comment: Have you tried temporarily copying it in your web root folder?

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215311/java-web-start-application-can-read-files-from-local-systems-but-not-write

Comment: I tried putting it in the project folder. But then the problem is the mp3 file can not be accessed unless I refresh the project in eclips and reload the web page.

Comment: If Eclipse  gets too annoying you can write your code in a text editor, save it in the proper place under Tomcat, and compile it with the commandline javac.